# Is there any issue to motherboard sensor if i always use temp sensor app like openhwminotor?

Tags: motherboard, temperature, sensors

I always minimise openhwmonitor which gives temp sensor readings. Is there any problem to my motherboard or is it stress system if i do it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be no additional stress on the system - most of these sensors are always reading and being acted on in the background anyway.  Depending on the sensor I guess its possible that it will slow the system down a wee bit while it is gathering the data.